# iPhone UITabBar - how do you switch tab views?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, switch-statement

Could you tell me how switching tab views work? Because in my "sendPressed" and "cancelPressed" methods I'm trying to switch from the second tab view to the first tab view. However as of right now I'm getting an error on the "[[array objectAtIndex:2] setSelectedSegmentIndex:1]" line.

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation SecondViewController

- (IBAction) sendPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    array = [[self tabBarController] viewControllers];
    [[array objectAtIndex:2] setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];
    [[self tabBarController] setViewControllers:array];
}

- (IBAction) cancelPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    array = [[self tabBarController] viewControllers];
    [[array objectAtIndex:2] setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];
    [[self tabBarController] setViewControllers:array];

}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    imageView.image = image;
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

...
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace that line with this:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

tab indexes start at 0. so index 0 would be the first tab, index 1 would be the second tab etc.

Comment: my pleasure! let me know if you run into anymore problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0; //first tab
```

Comment: no need for the `if`. If `self.tabBarController` is `nil`, calling `-selectedIndex` does not have an effect.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. I copied that out of one of my old apps, not knowing if it was needed or not :/

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just use

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;   // for first tab


// 1 for second tab
// 2 for third tab .....
```